# Update em array no MongoDB

Tags: banco-de-dados, mongodb, nosql

```js
{
    "_id" : "55dcb404478e7227203d3a65",
    "Nome" : "Grupo Familia",
    "Pessoas" : [ 
        {
            "PessoaId" : "55dcb425478e72207833e970",
            "Nome" : "Carlos",
            "Habilidades" : [
                {
                    "HabilidadeId" : "55dcb433478e7229b0e3ee07",
                    "Nome": "Pular",
                    "Macetes": [
                            {"Descricao" : "Usar um tênis macio"},
                            {"Descricao" : "Se alongar"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "HabilidadeId" : "55dcb425478e72207833e961",
                    "Nome" : "Correr"
                }
            ],
        }
    ],
}
```

Tenho essa collection no MongoDB e estou com a seguinte dúvida: Como faço para adicionar um novo macete na habilidade `"correr"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o `$addToSet` ou o `$push`. A diferença é se você quer elementos únicos no array ou não.

Existe um operador posicional `$` que você pode usar para atualizar elementos no índice que corresponda a sua query. Assim, se você "sabe" que há uma habilidade, mas não sabe sua posição, você deveria fazer a seguinte query:

```
db.grupos.update({ _id: "...", "Pessoas.Habilidades.Nome": "Correr" }, {
  "$addToSet": {
    "Pessoas.$.Habilidades.$.Macetes": { /*...*/ }  
  }
})
```

Se quiser remover elementos, terá de usar o `$pull` e para adicionar/remover mais de um elemento terá de usar o `$each`.

Links úteis:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/
- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/
- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/

Sugiro um índice em `Pessoas.Habilidades.Nome`.

### EDIT

Acabo de pesquisar um pouco mais e o que você quer fazer não é possível:

- http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays

Da documentação:

> O operador posicional $ não pode ser usado para buscas que percorrem mais de um array, como as buscas que percorrem arrays "nesteados" em outros arrays, porque a substituição pelo placeholder $ é um único valor

É necessário mudar a forma como os dados são modelados. Ou perder a atomicidade da operação.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set). Exemplo:

```
db.bla.update({"_id":"55dcb404478e7227203d3a65"},
{
    "$set": {
        "Pessoas.0.Habilidades.1.Macetes": [
            {
                "HabilidadeId": "idnovo",
                "Nome": "Pular"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

Comment: Responde a minha questão, porém no meu caso real, eu não sei qual o índice que a pessoa tem e nem o índice da habilidade, pode ser a decima pessoa da collection e a vigésima habilidade, Como faria para inserir uma manchete nesse caso ? ( sem inserir o número do indice diretamente)

Comment: Você sabe o PessoaId e o HabilidadeId? Se souber, usa eles na query em vez do "_id". Já na hora de manipular o array, poderia usar $push. Tem várias operações específicas pra manipular array, dá uma olhada aqui: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Comment: Qual a sintaxe para usar esses id's? Suponhamos que PessoaId = "teste1" e HabilidadeId = "teste2", como eu faria essa query ?

Comment: Seria tipo isso: `db.bla.update({"Pessoas.Habilidades.HabilidadeId" : "55dcb425478e72207833e961"}`, procurando direto o `HabilidadeId`.

Comment: Eu fiz dessa forma também e no $set usei isso :
"$set": {
        "Pessoas.$.Habilidades.$.Macetes": [
            {
                "HabilidadeId": "idnovo",
                "Nome": "Pular"
            }
        ]
    }

Porem nao funciona

Comment: Essa pergunta também pode ajudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821392/how-to-update-value-of-a-key-in-a-list-of-a-json-in-mongo

Comment: Dessa forma eu conseguiria chegar até Habilidades, mas não até macetes ..

Comment: Discussão tá ficando muito longa, vamo levar pro chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha